# Button is unclickable

Tags: html, css

Currently we make use of nice flat ccs-only buttons that show a push-down effect onclick. They have a weird behaviour:

```
.button {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #32a2f0;
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1e87cc;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
.button:hover {
    background: #1e87cc !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0169AD;
}
.button:active {
    border-bottom: 0px !important;
    border-top: 2px solid #0169AD;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6SeG8/

The problem is: When clicking the button at the top 2 to 4 pixels, the click event will not trigger. The css :active state does trigger, but the action of the button does not.

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using an `after` pseudo-element:

```
.button:active:after{
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppL6U/4/)

Note, that it doesn't work in IE7 and earlier.

Comment: This did look like the answer, but when I put text above and below the button the absolute positioned pseudo :after makes the text clickable. So, therafter I made the button's position relative, and then the fix is gone 

http://jsfiddle.net/ppL6U/3/

Comment: I've been playing with your :after element, and the solution for the problem with the top click was to position the :after element correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/ppL6U/5/

Comment: Edited it a little, try it now. By the way, `:after` is CSS2, and `::after` is CSS3. Both should work.

Comment: Yeah, my edit is pretty much the same. I also moved it to `:active:after` since there was a weird bug in http://jsfiddle.net/ppL6U/1/ where the whole area would become clickable instead of just the button when setting up percentages.

Comment: The :after pseudo element does indeed result to the right click behaviour. Important to mention is the need of position:relative on the button, and the top:-4px on the :after-element.

Answer (score 4):

It's because of the borders and the top margin you're applying. Rather than specifying `border-top: 0px;`, etc., you should instead give a transparent border. You can then give extra width to the top border to make up for the margin:

```css
.button {
    ...
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
}

.button:active {
    ...
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid #0169AD; /* Added 2px to this, instead of 2px margin */
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/6SeG8/13/).

Also you really shouldn't need to use `!important` at all.

Comment: Agree on the `!important`, that unfortunately is an effect of a crappy Wordpress theme we bought.
But, no solution for the nice margin-top effect? That effect makes the button look like it really is pressed down.

Answer (score 2):

```
.button:active {
    border-bottom: 0px !important;
    border-top: 2px solid #0169AD;
    //margin-top:2px;  //this is the problem
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6SeG8/4/)

```
.button:hover {
    background: #1e87cc !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0169AD; // This may cause the onclick not to work when clicking form the bottom of the button
}
```

Comment: This does mess up the nice click behaviour where it looks like the button is pushed down.

Answer (score 0):

Try to press and hold button.

You can see if you press **in a middle of the button** then the button is dark blue (really pressed).

If you press **near the border** then the button cannot get 'mouseup' to raise 'click' event. So your javascript will never receive click event and triggered.

If you want the same behavior change border margin to transparent border with desired size.

Comment: Border margin? I think you are describing the wanted behaviour, but that does not solve the weird click behaviour when clicking on the top 2 to 4 px of the button.

Comment: I explained why event cannot be handled.

Answer (score -1):

One thing you can do is

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('button is clicked')"><span class="button">Click me</span></a>
```