# HTML Buttons not clickable

Tags: html, css, attributes, css-grid

I have a set of buttons for a calculator application with attributes. They are clickable when the CSS is turned off here is the relevant bits of code. Currently the buttons are not clickable in any sort of way. Any help on why they are not would be great

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
}

.grid>button {
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.outputD {
  grid-column: 1/ -1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.outputD .curDisplayed {
  font-size: 2%;
  color: black;
}

.double {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="outputD">
    <div data-cD class="curDisplayed"></div>
    <div data-pD class="prevDisplayed"></div>
  </div>
  <button data-operation class="double">AC</button>
  <button data-delete>DEL</button>
  <button data-number>1</button>
  <button data-number>2</button>
  <button data-number>3</button>
  <button data-number>4</button>
  <button data-number>5</button>
  <button data-number>6</button>
  <button data-number>7</button>
  <button data-number>8</button>
  <button data-number>9</button>
  <button data-number>0</button>
  <button data-number>.</button>
  <button data-operation>+</button>
  <button data-operation>-</button>
  <button data-operation>*</button>
  <button data-operation>/</button>
  <button data-operation class="double">=</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is clicking them supposed to do? You have no JavaScript.

Comment: What do you mean by *"when css is turned off"*? The code shown works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/mfxtqr5h/

Comment: Your question doesn’t have a JavaScript tag. Are you loading some library that provides the actions on a button being clicked?

Comment: I have a js script that should update the display and do the math for the calculator.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the CSS border around the buttons .....I replaced the border with border-top: 4px solid #0169AD; as another stack overflow post suggested and it fixed my issue (ref: [Button is unclickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008408/button-is-unclickable)). I still dont know why this works but it does. Now my buttons are clickable.

I had the same problem when working on a calculator app. Before I started to add the Javascript I noticed that my buttons were not clickable. I then added a button outside of the calculator container div that the rest of the buttons were contained in and it worked fine (just not the buttons inside the calculator container). I also noticed that when i turned off the border for the buttons in the CSS all the buttons seemed to work fine as expected. So the border was the issue (i tried to change the z-index of the border to keep it but it didn't work). I will keep researching why the border does this and what I can do about it.

This was my original code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 19%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 6em auto;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: end;
  color: white;
  font-size: 38px;
  padding: 30px 10px;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.calculator {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "output output output output"
    "clear clear backspace divide"
    "seven eight nine multiply"
    "four five six subtract"
    "one two three add"
    "zero zero zero equal";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 90px 90px 90px 90px 90px 90px;
}

.output {
  grid-area: output;
  background-color: black;
}

.clear {
  grid-area: clear;
  background-color: #d8d9db;
}

.backspace {
  grid-area: backspace;
  background-color: #d8d9db;
}

.divide {
  grid-area: divide;
  background-color: #df974c;
}

.multiply {
  grid-area: multiply;
  background-color: #df974c;
  padding: 10px;
}

.subtract {
  grid-area: subtract;
  background-color: #df974c;
}

.add {
  grid-area: add;
  background-color: #df974c;
}

.equal {
  grid-area: equal;
  background-color: #df974c;
}

.zero {
  grid-area: zero;
  background-color: #d8d9db;
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
  background-color: #d8d9db;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
  background-color: #d8d9db;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
  background-color: #d8d9db;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
  background-color: #d8d9db;
}

.five {
  grid-area: five;
  background-color: #d8d9db;
}

.six {
  grid-area: six;
  background-color: #d8d9db;
}

.seven {
  grid-area: seven;
  background-color: #d8d9db;
}

.eight {
  grid-area: eight;
  background-color: #d8d9db;
}

.nine {
  grid-area: nine;
  background-color: #d8d9db;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
    <title>Calculator App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="calculator">
      <!-- Row 1 -->
      <div class="output">0</div>
      <!-- Row 2 -->
      <button class="clear border">C</button>
      <button class="backspace border">BS</button>
      <button class="divide border white">/</button>
      <!-- Row 3 -->
      <button class="seven border">7</button>
      <button class="eight border">8</button>
      <button class="nine border">9</button>
      <button class="multiply border white">x</button>
      <!-- Row 4 -->
      <button class="four border">4</button>
      <button class="five border">5</button>
      <button class="six border">6</button>
      <button class="subtract border white">-</button>
      <!-- Row 5 -->
      <button class="one border">1</button>
      <button class="two border">2</button>
      <button class="three border">3</button>
      <button class="add border white">+</button>
      <!-- Row 6 -->
      <button class="zero border">0</button>
      <button class="equal border white">=</button>
    </div>
    <button class="random">Click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are giving border with color white, its not like your button is not clickable, try by removing  "border: 1px solid white;" from the css .grid>button

Comment: What difference does the border make to whether element can be clicked or not?

Answer (score -2):

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
}

.grid>button {
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.grid>button:hover {
  background-color:lightgray;/*effect*/
}

.outputD {
  grid-column: 1/ -1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.outputD .curDisplayed {
  font-size: 2%;
  color: black;
}

.double {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="outputD">
    <div data-cD class="curDisplayed"></div>
    <div data-pD class="prevDisplayed"></div>
  </div>
  <button data-operation class="double">AC</button>
  <button data-delete>DEL</button>
  <button data-number>1</button>
  <button data-number>2</button>
  <button data-number>3</button>
  <button data-number>4</button>
  <button data-number>5</button>
  <button data-number>6</button>
  <button data-number>7</button>
  <button data-number>8</button>
  <button data-number>9</button>
  <button data-number>0</button>
  <button data-number>.</button>
  <button data-operation>+</button>
  <button data-operation>-</button>
  <button data-operation>*</button>
  <button data-operation>/</button>
  <button data-operation class="double" onclick="console.log('working');">=</button>
</div>
```

everything is working,
try clicking `=` button,
it will log in console.

> **Edit: Added effect** *of clicking* **when hovered**